# MVC 3: Return immuteable objects from cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, caching

I have an MVC 3 app that calls an external API to get data.  The API returns XML which I then serialize into objects.  Some of these objects do not change throughout the day so I cache them in order to reduce overhead.  My problem is that, if I get an item out of the cache and manipulate it, it changes the cached value as well.  I assume this is because only a reference to the cached item is returned.  I am using System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache to cache the objects.  Is there a way to return an item from the cache as an immutable object?  Or easily return a clone of the object?  I have tried deserializing the cached value back to XML then serializing it into a new object and though this works, it adds a lot of overhead and causes the site to perform very poorly under load.  I could implement ICloneable for each item, but then I have to write a deep clone method for each of my classes, which will take a lot of time and possibly have the same overhead problem serializing does.  I'm wondering if there is a quicker way.

Lets say I have a list of people cached. If I do this:

```
var people = Cache.Get<List<Person>>("people");
people.Remove(p => p.LastName != "Smith");
return View(people);
```

This will remove all people from the list whose last name is not Smith from both the view AND the cached list. Future Gets of that item will only return Smiths.

I can get around this by doing:

```
var people = Cache.Get<List<Person>>("people");
var viewlist = people.Where(p => p.LastName == "Smith").ToList();
return View(viewlist);
```

This does not affect the cached value.  Obviously I can do this everywhere in my code, but given the number of items I have cached, I'd have to be really sure to do this every time.  It would be much nicer if I could have the code throw a compile time (or even a run time) error if I try to edit an object obtained from cache.

My caching methods:

```
static object lockobj = new object();
public static T Get<T>(string index) //where T : new()
{
    T data;
    lock (lockobj)
    {
        data = (T)_cache[index];
    }
    return data;
}

public static T CacheInsert<T>(T obj, string index, CacheDependency dependencies,
        DateTime absoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback callback)
{
    T data;
    lock (lockobj)
    {
        data = (T)_cache[index];
        if (data == null)
        {
            _cache.Insert(index, obj, dependencies, absoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration, priority, callback);
            data = obj;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of List collection type you are using. List provide reference to the current collection. You have to copy your collection and run the filter if you don't want to modify your cache collection. Or return ienumarable from cache that will not allowed to modify current collection and do the needful thing like filter.

If you need example of it please let me know.